# Parameterized dynamic sql query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a list of keywords that i store in a list.

To fetch records from a table, am using the following query:

```
sqlBuilder.Append("SELECT name, memberid FROM members WHERE");
StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string item in keywords)
            {
            sqlBuilder.AppendFormat(" LOWER(Name) LIKE '%{0}%' AND", item); 
            }
string sql = sqlBuilder.ToString();
```

As you might have noticed, my query is vulnerable to sql injection, thus i want to use parameters using SqlCommand(). I have tried the following but still doesn't work:

```
foreach (string item in keywords)
            {    
                sqlBuilder.AppendFormat(" LOWER(Name) LIKE '%' + @searchitem + '%' AND", item);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlBuilder.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchitem",item);
             }
```

Where could i be making the mistake, or rather, how should i got about it?

Comment: Because every time you iterate your `keywords`, you creating new `SqlCommand`. I think you should use `AppendFormat` in your `foreach` loop, then create `SqlCommand` and add your parameters outside of your `foreach` loop.

Comment: I suggest to print out cmd.CommandText, you'll see it's not a well formed SQL query (you're doing everything inside your loop). Moreover wildcard will fit better together with parameter's value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are doing a few things wrong here:

- You give all your parameters the same name `@searchitem`. That won't work. The parameters need unique names.
- You create a new SqlCommand for each item. That won't work. Create the SqlCommand *once* at the beginning of the loop and then set `CommandText` once you are done creating the SQL.
- Your SQL ends with `AND`, which is not valid syntax.

Improvement suggestions (not wrong per se, but not best practice either):

- As Frederik suggested, the usual way is to put the `%` tokens in the parameter, rather than doing string concatenation inside the SQL.
- Unless you explicitly use a case-sensitive collation for your database, comparisons should be case-insensitive. Thus, you might not need the `LOWER`.

Code example:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
sqlBuilder.Append("SELECT name, memberid FROM members ");

var i = 1;
foreach (string item in keywords)
{
    sqlBuilder.Append(i == 1 ? " WHERE " : " AND ");
    var paramName = "@searchitem" + i.ToString();
    sqlBuilder.AppendFormat(" Name LIKE {0} ", paramName); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, "%" + item + "%");

    i++;
}
cmd.CommandText = sqlBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: Good suggestions. I have done away with the `AND` part.
Also, am not using a case sensitive db collation, thus i think i will do away with the `LOWER` keyword too. 
How do i got about using the `%` tokens into the parameter?

Comment: Helps much but still no results. When i step through the code, the query is `SELECT name, memberid FROM members WHERE  Name LIKE @searchitem1  AND  Name LIKE @searchitem2`.
When i copy this into a query editor and manually enter the search keywords as `SELECT name, memberid FROM members WHERE  Name LIKE '%john%'  AND  Name LIKE '%smith%'`  it returns results. What could be the problem?

Comment: @mutiemule: Sounds like the problem might be elsewhere. What do you do with the SqlCommand afterwards? Do you get any error?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I were still passing the `sqlBuilder.ToString()` string to the return statement instead of passing `cmd`. Works fine now. Thank you indeed.

Comment: I know this is old but I'm curious how cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, "%" + item + "%"); is actually working since cmd hasn't been associated to anything besides an default SQLCommand() object. I would think this would fail to replace anything.

Comment: @VictorLearned: AddWithValue does not replace anything. The SqlCommand simply *stores* the parameter for later use. Likewise, when `CommandText` is assigned to, again, SqlCommand just *stores* the string. Later, when the command is actually *executed* (not shown in the code example above), both the command string and the parameters are sent to SQL Server, which does whatever magic is necessary to ensure that *this* SQL command is executes with *these* parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Do not put the wildcard characters in your querystring, but add them to your parameter-value:

```
sql = "SELECT name FROM members WHERE Name LIKE @p_name";
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_name", "%" + item + "%");
```

When you add the wildcard characters inside your query-string, the parameter will be escaped, but the wildcard chars will not; that will result in a query that is sent to the DB that looks like this:

```
SELECT name FROM members WHERE Name LIKE %'somename'%
```

which is obviously not correct.

Next to that, you're creating a SqlCommand in a loop which is not necessary.  Also, you're creating parameters with a non-unique name, since you're adding them in a loop, and the parameter always has the same name.
You also need to remove the last AND keyword, when you exit the loop.

Comment: Valid point, but it's *not* the reason why his query doesn't work.

Comment: Please note that am using an sqlbuilder. Tried getting this work in the sqlbuilder to no avail.