# Parameterized dynamic sql query with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, parameterized-query

I had a Program   in c# which would run queries using a dynamically created string which would be used as a query.

Now due to possibility of SQL injection, I want to use parameterized queries to generate the same.

Was looking at  [Parameterized dynamic sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345860/parameterized-dynamic-sql-query) and that is mostly what I want, but then I want multiple parameters in the same sequence and not in different sequences.
i.e I want something like

```
(Where value in ({0}, {1}, {2}), param0 , param1, param2 )
```

The answer in that thread is

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
sqlBuilder.Append("SELECT name, memberid FROM members ");

var i = 1;
foreach (string item in keywords)
{
    sqlBuilder.Append(i == 1 ? " WHERE " : " AND ");
    var paramName = "@searchitem" + i.ToString();
    sqlBuilder.AppendFormat(" Name LIKE {0} ", paramName); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, "%" + item + "%");

    i++;
}
cmd.CommandText = sqlBuilder.ToString();
```

If I use this for my query, this would generate something like

```
where Value In param0 and value in param1 and value in param2
```

which if I'm not mistaken is terrible in terms of server performance.

So how do I get something similar to

```
sqlBuilder.AppendFormat(" Name IN {0} , {1} , {2} ", paramName0 , paramName1 , paramName2 );
```

for a parameterized dynamic query?

All the methods that I have tried compiles ok, but then returns run time errors.

Can't seem to figure what I'm doing wrong. :(
Any help?

Comment: Do you need to support multiple flavors of database engines or are you only targeting MS SQL Server ?

Comment: @user957902 OP has mysql in tags...

Comment: Need to support MySQL only. (No MS SQL).

Comment: @Alex Monday morning and not enough caffeine intake yet :P