# Searching using multiple keywords with a parameter in C# SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, search, parameters

I'm trying to do a search through the `comments` column of my table, but I can't get it to work using multiple keywords. For example, my table looks something like this:

```
Items
-------
name | comments
foo    first example comment
bar    second example comment
```

My search query looks like this:

```
SELECT name, comments
FROM Items
WHERE comments LIKE @comments
```

And I'm using my command parameter like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@comments", Item.commentSearchTerms));
```

To get `commentSearchTerms` my Item class has two properties, `comments` and `commentSearchTerms`. The `comments` are retrieved from a Windows Form Text Box. The `commentSearchTerms` property grabs `comments` and transforms it so that it can be used in an SQLite query that would hopefully be able to handle multiple key words:

```
public string commentSearchTerms {
    get 
    {
        List<string> commentsList = comments.Split(' ').ToList<string>();
        string commentsTerms = "";

        if (commentsList.Count > 1)
        {
            commentsTerms = "%" + commentsList[0] + "%";

            for (int i = 1; i < commentsList.Count; i++) 
            {
                commentsTerms += " AND comments LIKE %" + commentsList[i] + "%";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            commentsTerms = "%" + commentsList[0] + "%";
        }

        return commentsTerms;
    }
}
```

This seems to work for individual search terms, such as searching for `"first"` or `"second"`, but when I try to search using multiple terms such as `"first example"` or `"second example"` I can't get any results to come up. I've tested my query by hard coding the search query like this:

```
SELECT name, comments
FROM Items
WHERE comments LIKE '%first%' AND comments LIKE '%example%'
```

And I'm able to successfully retrieve the data I need. However, when it comes to using SQLite Parameters I just can't seem to get it right. I've also tried adding `''` to the search terms so it looked like

```
commentsTerms = "'%" + commentsList[0] + "%'";
```

and

```
commentsTerms += " AND comments LIKE '%" + commentsList[i] + "%'";
```

to match the hard coded SQLite query, but that didn't seem to work either. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the way C# substitutes Parameters, but I'm not sure. I have a feeling that when C# substitutes the single search Parameter it adds `''` to each side making it look like `'%first%'` in the actual query, which would make sense why it works for single keywords.

I can also see how this would be a problem with multiple keywords, because if my theory is correct then C# is adding `''` on either side of my `commentsTerms`, which would definitely break my query. And if that's the case, then it makes solving this a lot more troublesome than I originally anticipated. Is there a better way to go about this?

EDIT:
Got my answer thanks to some advice from @juharr. I needed to dynamically build my query and add parameters. The code now looks like this:

```
string query = @"
    SELECT name, comments
    FROM Items
    WHERE ";

.
.
.

List<string> commentsTerms = comments.Split(' ').ToList<string>();
query += " comments LIKE @term0";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@term0", "%" + commentsTerms[0] + "%"));

if (commentsTerms.Count > 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < commentsTerms.Count; i++)
    {
        query += " AND comments LIKE @term" + i;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@term" + i, "%" + commentsTerms[i] + "%"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to create one parameter for each term and either append the wildcards to the values or append them in the query.  Then dynamically build the where statement and concatenate it into the query string.  You should not use parameters to pass sql code, just values.  Alternatively just concatenate `commentTerms` to the query and don't use a parameter.

Comment: @juharr Wouldn't concatenating `commentTerms` to the query make it susceptible to SQL code injection though?

Comment: Yes, which is why creating one parameter for each term would be the better choice.  Ultimately you want something like `Where comments like @term1 and comments like @term2 and comments like @term3`  or `comments like '%' + @term1 + '%'` if you don't add the wildcards to the values you assign to each parameter.

Comment: Check out this question and it's accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345860/parameterized-dynamic-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Got it working and edited the question to include my changes.